# Dropdown List in KendoUI

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I am working with KendoUI, I created drop down list with Json data by using below code..

```
$("#locationdropdownList").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "LocationDescription",
        dataValueField: "LocationName",

            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "******my url******",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },

                }
            })
    });
```

It's working fine..But, my requirement is.. I want to show my custom value as the default one of drop down list(i.e my custom value will be appear on the top of the drop down list view, remain json data will display after custom one).

How can I do this.. Please give me solution for this..
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lokesh, you can use optionLabel property of the kendo ddl  :

```
$("#locationdropdownList").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "LocationDescription",
        dataValueField: "LocationName",
        optionLabel: " my custom value ...."
```